# error al instalar r y rstudio : Err:9 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux...​ focal-cran40/ Release 404 Not Found [IP: 13.227.201.52 443]

Tags: r, linux, ubuntu, rstudio

cuando ejecuto en la terminal de linux(UBUNTU 20.04 LTS) :

```
$ sudo apt-get update
```

sale esto:

```
Err:9 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux...​ focal-cran40/ Release
```

404  Not Found [IP: 13.227.201.52 443]

E: El repositorio «https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux...​ focal-cran40/ Release» no tiene un fichero de Publicación.
N: No se puede actualizar de un repositorio como este de forma segura y por tanto está deshabilitado por omisión.
N: Vea la página de manual apt-secure(8) para los detalles sobre la creación de repositorios y la configuración de usuarios.

Answer (score 0):

Lo mas seguro que copiaste la linea de un video de youtube...
elimina el repositorio:

sudo add-apt-repository --remove 'deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux... focal-cran40/'

Lo mas recomendable que te vayas a la pagina oficial de R, y sigue los pasos

https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/

Saludos